# Adding days to a date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, date

Do you know how to get the date after adding a fraction of day? For example, on Oracle I used to do to get a date:

```
select ((to_date('31/12/1969 190000','dd/mm/yyyy hh24miss')) + 1388655926 /86400) from dual
```

However, I have found that MySQL doesn't have a dual table, so this is directly and I have to use addtime function, but I haven't gotten the right result:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('1969-12-31 19:00:00', INTERVAL 1388655926 /86400 DAY);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? If you just want to convert a Unix timestamp to a MySQL date/Time you can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` Mysql reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: The 19:00 implies that you are trying to second-guess the timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MySQL `DATE_ADD()` function. In MySQL the `ADDTIME()` returns a time or datetime after adding a time value with a time or datetime.
The `DATE_ADD()` function adds a specified time interval to a date.

Syntax:
    DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)

Try this:
    SELECT DATE_ADD('1969-12-31 19:00:00',INTERVAL 1388655926/86400 DAY)

Here is the [W3Schools reference page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp).